# Getting the value and items in checkListBox

Tags: c#

I am writing a Windows Forms application that has a checkListBox. I have a databinded checkListBox value that is connected to my sql db. I want to write a loop to loop through a list of checked items and get its value (not index). I am wondering is there a way to do it just like the comboBox.SelectedValue?

```
foreach(var item in checkListBox.CheckedItems){

    //get the value of that 
    string query = select * from employeeId where '"+checkListBox.SelectedValue+"'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
foreach(object item in checkListBox.CheckedItems)
{
     DataRowView dt = item as DataRowView;
     string str = dt["nameHere"];
     // some code
}
```

Comment: can I do this with sql query?

Comment: @DragonBorn:-  I don't think it would be a good idea to do it using sql query.

Comment: I see. thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a try

Comment: @DragonBorn:- If you can bind the result of your sql query to a DataTable then you can cast it to a DataRowView and then take its Row property to get a DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the item to the relevant type (DataRowView?)

```
foreach(var item in checkListBox.CheckedItems){

    var val = item as DataRowView; 
    // retrieving the relevant values

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it other way as well

```
List<object> _checkedItems = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

This will give you all the checked items. If you want to pass this into sql query then you can do something like

```
string delimeter = "','";
string _selectedItems ="'"+ _checkedItems.Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimeter + j).ToString()+"'";
```

and pass it in your sql query

```
   string query = select * from employeeId where somevalue in ("+_selectedItems +")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
foreach(var item in checkListBox.CheckedItems){

     var value = (item as ListItem).Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Roy, I can only find ListViewItem though

Answer (score 0):

The items in the `CheckedListBox` and checks every other item in the list. Using the Items property to get the CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection to get the Count of items.

Using the [`SetItemCheckState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemcheckstate.aspx) and [`SetItemChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked.aspx) methods to set the check state of an item. For every other item that is to be checked, SetItemCheckState is called to set the CheckState to Indeterminate, while SetItemChecked is called on the other item to set the checked state to Checked.

```
//checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(a,true);

for ( int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++ )
{
    if(checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        string query = select * from employeeId where '" + checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString() + "';
    }

}
```